# Django No module named 'PIL' only in production

Tags: python, django, apache

I get an error when trying to upload an image using the Django admin

> ModuleNotFoundError at /admin/home/image/16/change/
>
> No module named 'PIL`

The strange thing is, this only appears when I run the Django site with apache, when I run the server using `sudo python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80` it works just fine. Additionally, when I activate the virtual environment I have for Django, I can run `import PIL` just fine. I can also do this when running the Django shell with `sudo python3 manage.py shell`. The package is also shown to be installed when I run `pip3 freeze` and `pip3 list`.

Another note, I can't run the `wsgi.py` file in my Django project/

I'm not sure what will help, but here are some files I think may be important.

apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Servername www.ubspy.org
  Servername ubspy.org

  DocumentRoot /home/ubspy/django/

  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubspy/django/ubspy/wsgi.py

  ErrorLog /home/ubspy/django/error.log

  Alias /static/ /home/ubspy/django/static/
  Alias /media/ /home/ubspy/django/media/
  Alias /php/ /var/www/html/

  <Directory /home/ubspy/django/static/>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /home/ubspy/django/media/>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  WSGIDaemonProcess ubspy.org python-home=/home/ubspy/django/env python-path=/home/ubspy/django/
  WSGIProcessGroup ubspy.org

  <Directory /home/ubspy/django/ubspy/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
  </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for ubspy project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Static files (CSS, JavaScipt, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubspy/django/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'favicon/'),
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
secretFile = open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ubspy/secret.dat'), 'r')
SECRET_KEY = secretFile.read()
secretFile.close()

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.16', 'ubspy.org', 'www.ubspy.org']

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'poem.apps.PoemConfig',
    'mewsicgen.apps.MewsicgenConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ubspy.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ubspy.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Any help would be apprechiated, thank you!

Comment: Probably not the problem, but you shouldn't be doing any of those things with sudo.

Comment: @Daniel Would using sudo actually prevent anything from working?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm only running sudo for accessing the secret data file I have, and accessing port 80 when using `runserver`. If you think I should run it without sudo I can certainly try that.

Comment: have to say your `python-path` is strange with respect to the `python-home`: usually the virtualenv isn't inside the project directory. Are you sure `manage.py` is in this _/django_ directory at the same level as _/django/env_?

Comment: @dirkgroten yes, it is, the `env` folder is in the same dir as `manage.py`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Pillow lib.

```
pip install Pillow
```

More details about [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)

Comment: As I said, I can import pillow just fine when I run `python3` or `sudo python3 manage.py shell`. When I run `pip3 freeze` it shows pillow is installed.

Comment: So, If you already installed the Pillow library. There is another problem. when you run the codebase via Apache, then It could not find the Pillow library. The Django project does not run actiual virtualenv where the Pillow library installed

Comment: Any ideas to what the problem would be? I can't find anything on it.

Comment: I don't have any idea about Apache. I always used Gunicorn, Nginx. sorry. 

But you can be following debug the problem. 
Active your virtual environment and run the project. If the project is running. Then it should have problem when you are going to run the project via apache. In this case I have no idea about apache.

Answer (score 0):

if you have different versions of python installed, check that apache runs your script with python3.

sometimes if you installed a package only for a user or in an environment, when you run script form another user or outside environment you got this error. as far as I know, Apache runs the script with another user than root, so that can cause the problem.

Comment: The only wsgi version I have installed requires python3, so I don't think that's the case. Plus, if it was the wrong version, wouldn't there be other errors in the script somewhere?